# Can I search for my library in Apple TV app on macOS?

Tags: macos

In Apple TV app on my Mac I have a number of my video files in the library area for quick access (more than 50) but when I go to search in the search bar I immediately get taken to what Apple has for download.

I don’t understand why I can’t search my content first or exclusively.

Is it possible to find what I have in the library section?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you on Catalina or Big Sur? Please edit in any pertinent facts. I edited some tone out of the question to avoid downvotes. It’s a perfectly good thing to prefer your content be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a direct quote from "[Searching Your Own Library with Apple TV App](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250739344)" on Apple Community:

> Found a solution! (Obtuse UI design...sheesh).
>
> View...Show Filter Field
>
> This brings up a search bar that will look in your library. UNFORTUNATELY...it turns off every time you flip between tv or movies or close the app. But it will search your library.